# How to make Photoshop CS5 open a document at 100% zoom

Tags: photoshop-cs5

It's very annoying when opening up documents in Photoshop and they fit to screen which is usually 33% or 66% in my case. Is there a way to set the zoom at 100% regardless of how big the document is?

Using control +/= key is better than having to click in the box, type 100 and then hit enter, but it would be even better if it just defaulted to 100%.

Comment: Welcome to Photo.SE Nick. Questions specific to photoshop are actually off-topic here. In a few minutes your question will be closed.

Comment: @Alan, I apologize for posting in the wrong place. I'm sure moving it would be a better solution than just closing it (Although it may not satisfy your power trip) :).

Comment: It was closed by non-mods. A mod would have to move it, so...

Comment: FTR voted to close it *and* flagged to move. I think that's the right thing to do. We can continue this discussion back on http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/ if anyone likes. :)

Comment: Hi Nick. This wasn't about a power trip. Currently Photo.SE doesn't give us the ability to move a page, based on being off-topic (yet). So having it closed by community, will bring it to moderator's attention and they will move it as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The fast way of switching to 100% zoom in Photoshop is `CTRL`+`ALT`+`0`(on QWERTY section of keyboard).